# Configuration Deployment workflow of Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS [Elastic Beanstalk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) mentions 2 types of deployment under 'Platform Hooks' section,

- Instance Deployment
- Configuration Deployment

A workflow is also provided for [Instance Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.workflow)

Looking at the workflow and the description, we assume `commands` and `container_commands` are run during config deployment also. But from my experience that is not the case. Not sure what else is different in Config workflow.

Does anyone know the full workflow for Configuration Deployment ?